# Is there any use of final String mainViewPaths[]={};?

Tags: java

When I was started learning Java 1 year ago. Being from a C background, I found many things in Java strict, such as unreachable statements due to infinite loops, etc.

So, is there any use of the variable declaration `final String mainViewPaths[]={};`?. What can we do with that empty array reference? We cannot even reuse the variable since it's marked `final`. It doesn't result in any compiler errors. I'm asking this because I think Java developers kept aside everything that's possibly of no use or misleading.

Comment: A length-zero array is perfectly legal...

Comment: You can do sh*t in any language... But yeah, this cannot really serve any purpose, except as a reference empty array of some sort.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I know it's legal...but what's the use of final empty array initialization....why java compilers doesn't restrict it....

Comment: It can be used as a lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty array like the `mainViewPaths` variable can be used as an **[Null Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)**.

> In object-oriented computer programming, a Null Object is an object with defined neutral ("null") behavior.

Imagine this scenario:

- There are variables that are initialized with a reference to the `mainViewPaths` variable, e.g.

  ```
  String loginViewPaths[] = mainViewPaths; 
  String homeViewPaths[] = mainViewPaths;
  ```
- There are numerous places in the source code accessing the ViewPaths variables, e.g.:

  ```
  public String toString() {
      return mainViewPaths.toString();
  }    

  for(int i = 0; i < mainViewPaths.length; i++) {
      // iterate over all the mainViewPaths elements
  }
  ```
- If the `mainViewPaths` variable was initialized not with an empty array but simply with a `null` then in the above code before accessing the mainViewPaths variable there should be a check if the `mainViewPaths` variable is null, so the code should look like:

  ```
  public String toString() {
      return mainViewPaths != null ? mainViewPaths.toString() : null;
  }    

  for(int i = 0; i < mainViewPaths == null ? 0 : mainViewPaths.length; i++) {
      // iterate over all the mainViewPaths elements
  }
  ```
- So having a `Null Object` like the `mainViewPaths` variable allows to save a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: Yes, such a variable can be used instead of `null`. Then if there is any code accessing this variable it does not need a null check.

Comment: can you elaborate... `mainViewPaths==null` returns false they are not equal... I think I'm not getting you...

Comment: @pinkpanther I have added a scenario explaining why having such variable might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any use of the expression
>
> ```
> final String mainViewPaths[]={};
> ```

This is not an expression.  It's a field or variable declaration.

> What can we do with that empty array reference?

You can use it as a return value or parameter to a function.  You can assign it to a field or local variable of type `String[]`.

You can use it for its runtime type as in

```
myCollection.toArray(new String[0])
```

which passes an empty array to a collection so that the collection can use reflection to create an array of the same type and of the appropriate size.

> we cannot even reuse the variable since it's final

I don't know what you mean by this.  You can reuse it as much as you like.  You just can't reassign it.

> It doesn't result in any compiler error.

True.

> I'm asking this because I think Java developers kept aside everything that possibly of no use or misleading.

The things that are of no use or misleading to someone learning the language are different from those language features that are of no use or misleading to an expert or to someone writing a code generator.

The language designers allow this because it is a combination of two orthogonal features each of which is useful -- the ability to declare a field and initialize without mentioning the field name twice, and the ability to construct an array of length 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really change it, but you can still use it.  And it can actually be useful.  Imagine naming that `emptyArray`.  You can use that for comparison in other parts of the code and it would be very bad if other code could modify it.